# grub2 command line loaded instead ubuntu os

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a strange problem. After installing ubuntu on usb stick (at already installed ubuntu computer), after removing usb stick with installed ubuntu from computer I get the trouble: after booting to computer I get grub 2 command line.

How can I revert it to select ubuntu os by arrow keys (or load ubuntu strictly without grub, as just earlier)? Now, I need to put these commands in grub to automatic load ubuntu:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-52-generic root=/dev/sda2
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic
boot
```

Outputs of some commands:

```
$ sudo parted -l /dev/sda
Model: ATA WDC WD20EARX-00P (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   1993GB  1992GB  ext4
 3      1993GB  2000GB  7446MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

My `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=9310bdc0-b3f5-4258-ad7e-9d1de9dfb161 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=C4D0-4779  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=d835e59a-4205-4951-9bad-e0d586f52c52 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've need just manual boot to ubuntu and then just `sudo update-grub`